# Apache Beam Map, DoFn and Composite Transform

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to understand the difference is use cases between a Map function, a DoFn called from Pardo and a Composite transform.

I could achieve the same results with the below code for a list of transformations that I need to do for my pipeline. I made a sample of what I mean by multiple stages.

```
import apache_beam as beam

def myTransform(line):
   line = line * 10
   line = line + 5
   line = line - 2
   return line

class myPTransform(beam.PTransform):
  def expand(self, pcoll):
    # return pcoll | beam.Map(myTransform)
    pcol_output = (pcoll 
                   | beam.Map(lambda line: line * 10)
                   | beam.Map(lambda line: line + 5)
                   | beam.Map(lambda line: line - 2)
    )
    return pcol_output

class mydofunc(beam.DoFn):
   def process(self, element):
    element = element * 10
    element = element + 5
    element = element - 2
    yield element
   
with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    lines = p | beam.Create([1,2,3,4,5])
    
    ### Map Function
    manual = (lines
              | "Map function" >> beam.Map(myTransform)
              | "Print map" >> beam.Map(print))
    
    ### Composite Ptransform
    ptrans = (lines
              | "ptransform call" >> myPTransform()
              | "Print ptransform" >> beam.Map(print))
    
    ### Do Function
    dofnpcol = (lines
              | "Dofn call" >> beam.ParDo(mydofunc())
              | "Print dofnpcol" >> beam.Map(print))
```

On what scenarios should I use a DoFn and a Composite Transform?
I might be missing a bigger picture here for the difference between these 3 options.
Any insights would be really helpful.

I saw a question on [Apache Beam: DoFn vs PTransform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47706600/apache-beam-dofn-vs-ptransform)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this operation, the transformation is done only inside a worker :

```py
   ### Map Function
    manual = (lines
              | "Map function" >> beam.Map(myTransform)
              | "Print map" >> beam.Map(print))
```

For this second operation, the 3 transformations can be done on multiple workers :

```py
    ### Composite Ptransform
    ptrans = (lines
              | "ptransform call" >> myPTransform()
              | "Print ptransform" >> beam.Map(print))
```

In this last operation, the result is exactly the same as the first example with `Map`.
Behind the `Map` operator uses a `DoFn`, but with the possibility to directly pass a function (or lambda) as parameter. It's interesting to remove boilerplate code and directly call a transformation from an element to another element :

```py
    
    ### Do Function
    dofnpcol = (lines
              | "Dofn call" >> beam.ParDo(mydofunc())
              | "Print dofnpcol" >> beam.Map(print))
```

The choice depends on different criteria, in your example the transformation isn't expensive and you can use the first and third example.

But in real-world application, big volume and more complexe operations, you can choose the second approach.

The composite `PTransform` allows to assemble several transformations together and this kind of class and design allow a reusability in other places of the pipeline or in other pipelines.

Comment: Thank you @Mazlum. If the volume is too high what is the best option between a Composite Transform and using a DoFn?

Comment: A composite transform is more used to separate the responsability in a different place. For an usual transformation, you can use a DoFn or Map. If you have 2 immutable transformations, you can use 2 DoFn or Map. If these 2 transformations can be reuse together or if you want to separate this responsability, it’s better to create a composite Transform. For one Map versus several Map, it depends if the transformation is heavy. Most of times we compose multiple immutable transformations.